# Триггер, который не дает вставлять дублирующую запись

Tags: firebird

Доброе утречко! Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли написать триггер, который вставляет только не повторяющиеся  записи? У меня не получается. Если кто сталкивался с такой проблемкой, помогите.

Comment: Может быть удобней unique повесить? Или обязательно триггер?

Comment: Да нет,триггер не так уж и важен, главное результат

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужен здесь триггер. Достаточно поставить уникальный индекс на таблицу.
Вот команда:

```
create unique index <имя индекса> on <имя таблицы> (<поле1>, <поле2>, <поле3>)
```

поле1, поле2, поле3 - поля, по которым определяется уникальность записи.

Еще решение зависит от требования к задаче. Если надо вставить первую запись из повторяющихся или нужна гарантированная уникальность, то нужен вариант с уникальным индексом. Минус этого варианта - это то, что нужно обрабатывать ошибки при вставке дублирующихся записей. Во все остальных случаях - команда `UPDATE OR INSERT`.

Comment: Ну лучше так. Это-ж представьте, какая нагрузка на БД, когда она постоянно перед вставкой будет делать операцию поиска по этому параметру?! О_о

Comment: База будет не сильно большая, потому, что я планирую выгружать устаревшую информацию в архив и при при острой необходимости брать из него данные.
Спасибо, за ценный совет, я написал процедурку которая не вставляет данные если есть дубликат пришедшей записи.

Как можно обрабатывать ошибки при вставке дублирующихся записей? Я просто этого еще не делал, вдруг прижмет, так хоть буду знать, что делать.

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант, использовать вместо **INSERT** команду **UPDATEorINSERT**

[Описание](http://firebirdsql.su/doku.php?id=update_or_insert)